# Unable to import yaml (pyyaml) on travis-ci using python 3.6

Tags: pip, travis-ci, python-3.6, pyyaml

I'm trying to test a python project which utilizes the `yaml` package (pyyaml) using travis-ci.

```
sudo: required
python: "3.6"
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
  - sudo pip3 install pyyaml 
script:
  - ./setup.py test
```

However travis keeps giving me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I've tried using plain `pip` to install pyyaml, as well as the ubuntu package `python3-yaml` with no luck. I can get it to work on a local VM with ubuntu, just not in `travis-ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ModuleNotFoundError" indicates that it is indeed Python 3.6 that generates the error Python <= 3.5 would give a module error. I would tend to use `/path/to/python setup.py test`, but it already looks like you have the right Python there.

That leaves that pip3 might not install where you think it installs, so you should at least do:

```
- sudo /path/to/python36 -m pip install pyyaml
```

to make sure you get the pip3 that you are expecting, and that you are not using some default system Python 3.5 or earlier.

You could also consider installing `virtualenv` with a known path, and install `pyyaml` in there and then run your `setup.py` with a full path of the python from there.